# OSError: SavedModel file does not exist at: sh./model/traffic_sign.model/{saved_model.pbtxt|saved_model.pb}

Tags: python, tensorflow

Raspberry Pi 4

TensorFlow version: 2.2.0

Python version: 3.7.3

Installed using: pip

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np
from math import sqrt, pow
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import img_to_array
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model
import time

norm_size = 32

model = load_model("./model/traffic_sign.model")
```

Does anyone know what is wrong with the code?
I got these error

`Traceback (most recent call last): File "utils.py", line 9, in <module> model = load_model("./model/traffic_sign.model") File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/saving/save.py", line 189, in load_model loader_impl.parse_saved_model(filepath) File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/saved_model/loader_impl.py", line 113, in parse_saved_model constants.SAVED_MODEL_FILENAME_PB)) OSError: SavedModel file does not exist at: ./model/traffic_sign.model/{saved_model.pbtxt|saved_model.pb}`

Comment: remove the `.model`

Comment: I did that but I still got the error

OSError: SavedModel file does not exist at: ./model/traffic_sign/{saved_model.pbtxt|saved_model.pb}

Comment: try a full path to the model

Comment: I did that based on my google search didn't work...can you please show me your example

Comment: Can you check this [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/save_and_load#savedmodel_format) to save and load the model and let us know if still issue persists? Thanks!